# Include external class php

Tags: php, include, external

How can include a external class in a php file?
example:

```
//Test.class.php

<?php 
class Test{
    function print($param){
        echo $param;
        }
    }
?>

//######################################################

//test.php
<?php
include('http://www.test.com/Test.class.php');

 $obj = new Test();

echo $obj->print("hola");
?>
```

The class is on another server. I have enabled the `allow_url_include` and `allow_url_fopen`.
Why can't I call the function `print`?

Comment: What error message are you getting? Also, it's not a good idea to remotely include files, why not downloading a version locally and use it (I can't see `include` or any similar thing btw). Also, try to reformat the question so it's readable.

Answer (score 2):

The remote file must output the php source code, not execute it.

To output the PHP code instead of executing you could simply remove the `.php` extension from the file.

PS: Are you really, really, really sure you need remote inclusion? It's a ***BIG*** security risk!

Comment: I recommend you use xml-rpc, soap, rest... something like it.

Answer (score 0):

What you're including from the other server isn't the code behind the PHP but the output from it (if you visit that page in a browser you aren't seeing the PHP code if you view source right?)

You either need to reconfigure the other server not to execute the code but display it (not a good idea if it's in any way shared or needs to execute it's own code), or rename the other file to something that isn't first interpretted (try `otherfile.php.txt`)

Comment: it`s works. I rename the file from .php to .txt this is just a experiment. I know is a security risk.
thanks alls.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> (...) If the target server interprets the target file as PHP code, variables may be passed to the included file using a URL request string as used with HTTP GET. This is not strictly speaking the same thing as including the file and having it inherit the parent file's variable scope; the script is actually being run on the remote server and the result is then being included into the local script.

Probably the server, you are trying to get the file from, executes the PHP file and only the result (which is empty) is included. You would have to configure the server in such a way that it outputs the PHP code. But this is not a good idea if it is sensible code.